# passing in interfaces in Swift to configuring view methods

Tags: swift

In iOS examples, I'll often see setting the object on a UITableViewCell subclass and then that subclass knows how to configure the view.

Pseudo-code

```
class MyCustomObject {
    var name = ""
}

class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func setMyCustomObject(obj: MyCustomObject) {
        nameLabel = obj.name
    }
}
```

I've been looking at some TypeScript/Angular code as well these days and I've seen patterns where they'll create an interface for the object.

more pseudo-code

```
interface ICustomInterface {
    name: String
}

class MyCustomObject : ICustomInterface {
    ...
}
```

Then you could do something in your view code just passing in the interface instead of the actual object.

```
setObjectForView(obj: ICustomInterface) {
    nameLabel = obj.name
}
```

Is this something that can be done in Swift to be more flexible down the line?  Or is it not really necessary?  When I try to do something like this in Swift, I get linker errors I do not understand so I'm wondering if this paradigm is even a good fit for Swift or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, that's a `protocol`. It's very powerful for certain problems, but it's not something worth applying to every cell.

If you do this, the better name would be `Nameable` since it's something you can name (like `Sliceable`, `Printable`, `Comparable`, etc). Leading prefixes like `I` is not good Swift style. It's hard to imagine it being worth the trouble for this particular example, though.